# Doxygen only include interface

Tags: c#, interface, doxygen, doxywizard, doxygen-wizard

I need to generate a doc with Doxygen, but ONLY interface type. No class! The project is very big.

I can use "I*.cs" in FILE_PATTERNS but I will then take all class that start with "I". So this is not a solution.

I can add @cond and @endcond to call class, but it will takes years...

The best would be to say only include "interface" type of file or to add a tag in the interface comment to include it in the generation (I do more need to include a few of my interfaces than to much data).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why not specify only your interface files in INPUT? Doxygen will generate documentation only for those files.